# A problem with the existence of limits of $\sin(P(n)\pi)$ and $\cos(P(n)\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $P$ be a nonconstant polynomial with constant term equal $0$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(P(n)\pi)$ and  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(P(n)\pi)$ exist.
>
> Prove or disprove: all coefficients of $P$ are rational.

The problem is based on my own investigations. [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291340/a-well-known-limit-with-sine-but-with-pn-instead-of-n). Both might be known, but I couldn't find results of that sort.

Comment: Related: the last paragraph in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/958350/42969.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is true. The following holds:

> **Theorem**: Let $P(x) = a_nx^n+...+a_0$ be a polynomial such that for some $j>0$, $a_j$ is irrational. Then $\sin(P(n)\pi)$ is a sequence dense in $[-1, 1]$.

[Look at my previous answer as a reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2870017/476484).